# How can I generate a printable overview of my .NET assembly?

Tags: .net, documentation

I've been tasked with reviewing an existing assembly and putting together a nice public API for it. The assembly is pretty large so I'd like to get an overview of its contents printed out so that I can easily browse through it and make notes.

Are there any tools out there that could help me out with this?

I've taken a look at NDoc but this generates the documentation over numerous pages. What I want is a single document that I can punt directly at a printer.

I was thinking that I could apply my own XSLT to the XML output that NDoc creates if need be but want to make sure there aren't any tools out there already before I start doing that work.

Comment: NDepend http://www.ndepend.com/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Framework Design Studio](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/fds). Although its actual purpose is to design, review and diff framework assemblies, you can also use it to export the definitions of an assembly to a file (RTF, DOC and XML). I've used it with RTF, DOC seems to hang - at least on my box. The result will be a file with all types (classes, interfaces, etc.) in the assembly nicely colored. Method bodies and other details are omitted, but I think that you didn't want them anyway.

Here is a example showing one FDS' own assemblies as an RTF export in Word:

[image: FDS RTF export in Word]

I should add that FDS is not exactly the sharpest tool in the shed, but for doing a "one time" export of even a large assembly it should be OK.

Comment: Thanks Christian that is absolutely brilliant, I'll check it out!

Comment: Had a few issues installing but once I got past that it did the trick perfectly!